# Fixar uma sidebar

Tags: html, css, formulário, menu, sidebar

Tenho dois componentes, um formulário e uma sidebar, quero deixar com que minha sidebar fique fixa na tela e quando eu for adicionando dados no formulário e salvando conforme vou inserindo a sidebar não se "mova". Nesse link ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/ri0Ma.jpg ) está como está a sidebar e o formulário, quando eu mexo no css da sidebar para mudar alguma configuração desconfigura tudo o formulário de lugar. Alguém pode me ajudar??

Css do formulário:

```
.list-wrapper {

    width: 112%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('./images/background.jpg');
    padding: 100px;
    margin-top: -18.4cm;
    margin-left: -3.5cm;
  }

  .card {

    margin-top: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 125px;
    padding: 10px;
  }


  .card-title {

    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 1.5em;
  }

  .card-subtitle {

    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #999;
  }
```

Css da sidebar:

```
.sibebar-navegacao {

    position: fixed;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;

}

.menu-item {

    display: block;
    width: 9%;
    height: 35vh;
    padding: 13px;
    background-color: #4682B4;
    color: #54FF9F;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Sidebar:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'


import { auth } from './base'


import './sidebar.css'


class Sidebar extends Component {


    render(props){

        return(
            <nav className='sidebar-navegacao'>
                <NavLink className='menu-item' to={`/admin/professor`}>PROFESSOR</NavLink>
                <NavLink className='menu-item' to={`/admin/turma`}>TURMA</NavLink>
                <NavLink className='menu-item' to={`/admin/disciplina`}>DISCIPLINA</NavLink>
            </nav>


        )
    } 

}

export default Sidebar
```

Formulário:

```
<div className='list-wrapper'>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSave}>

          <InputField
            refValue={ref => this.docente = ref}
            idValue='docente'
            typeValue='text'
            requiredValue={true}
            label='Docente'
            spanWidth="120px"
          />

          <InputField
            refValue={ref => this.disciplina = ref}
            idValue='disciplina'
            typeValue='text'
            requiredValue={true}
            label='Disciplina'
            spanWidth="80px"
          />


          <button type='submit'>Salvar Dados </button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Então, não sei como escrever de uma forma fácil. Mas por exemplo, quando eu adiciono algum dado no formulário, ele vai aumentando na tela, quando ele passa do local da sidebar a sidebar fica fixa e não acompanha o aumento da parte do formulário. Eu queria que conforme o formulário fosse aumentando quando insiro os dados, a sidebar acompanha também. Acho que é o máximo que consigo explicar..

Comment: Seria necessário colocar a estrutura do html, para vermos como os elementos se relacionam.

Comment: @dvd ai que tá, ele é fixo por um lado, mas não ocupa a tela toda, olha nesse modelo como ele fica de acordo com o que eu lhe disse ( https://imgur.com/a/nNwNyiv )

Comment: @MagicHat então, só que ficaria muito extenso pq estou fazendo por jsx/react, e o código dele é extenso e uso mais de um arquivo para mexer..

Comment: @dvd não mudou nada..

Comment: @MagicHat coloquei acima, e apenas uma parte do formulário, pq ele em si já é extenso o código.

Comment: @dvd então como faço para não ficar assim, e ficar "fixa" nos 100% da tela, pq sempre que mudo  css dela altera na posição do formulário..

Comment: O CSS está certo, com fixed e tudo. Quando vc rola a tela o sidebar sobe também como se não estivesse fixo?

Comment: @dvd sim, exato

Comment: Já experimentou trocar esse `className='list-wrapper'` por apenas `class='list-wrapper'`?

Comment: Parece que vc está usando um framework, não sei se isso vai afetar.

Comment: @dvd alterei aqui e não mudou nada.. E nao estou utilizando framework....

Comment: Acho que vai ter que analisar no Inspecionar Elemento do navegador pra ver o comportamento da div.

Comment: @dvd o erro era porque as medidas estavam em cm..

Comment: ah tah rs.......